# How to get github-like behaviour for ssh access on my git server

Tags: git, ssh, github

Suppose we have two separate github users: Foo and Bar. They own Quux and Waldo repositories respectively. So Foo can push to Foo/Quux and cannot push to Bar/Waldo. Opposite is right for Bar.
Then Foo cloned his Quux repository:

```
$ git clone ...
...
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:Foo/Quux.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Foo/Quux.git (push)
```

Seems while Foo has write access to Foo/Quux repository via `git` user he has not write access to Bar/Waldo repository via same user. Is there any way I can reach the same behaviour on my git server? Am I supposed to write custom `sshd` daemon for this purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) to get fine-grained access control to your git repositories over SSH where every user is identified by her SSH key.

In contrast to the already mentioned gitosis, Gitolite is still maintained and supports a more fine-grained control over the repository access.

If you want more of GitHub's functionality internally you should take a look at [GitLab](http://gitlabhq.com/) and of course [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) for fine grained access control to multiple repositories being shared across a team.

Comment: gitosis hasn't been updated in years - gitolite is the community-accepted alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If the repositories are on the same server, there is no way to distinguish two users with the same username. Even a custom sshd wouldn't work because it would see the incoming connection for user "git" only, not the original username.

We manage our permissions with either usernames or groups. So some users belong to the "developers" group that can push to certain repositories and others belong to "users" which can push to other repositories. Each user logs in with his/her own username.

Comment: "If the repositories are on the same server, there is no way to distinguish two users with the same username." - You can still use different SSH keys to distinguish the users like GitHub, gitosis, and Gitolite do.

Comment: Relying on ssh keys is not always feasible (like when you don't have yours with you). Sourceforge.net also goes the username route, in fact, it even uses a special notation ("user,project@git.sf.net") to enable roles.

Comment: Using usernames has a serious problem: it makes the URL of the repository different for each user. This is a show-stopper when using submodules, for example, and I bet is the main reason why GitHub and others use ssh keys.